# Class that stores a std::chrono::duration as a member?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-chrono

I want to create a class who's construct takes a `std::chrono::duration` argument and stores the result in a member so that I can later pass it into `std::this_thread::sleep_for()`.

I know I can write some function template that works like `sleep_for` as follows:

```
template <typename Rep, typename Period>
void mySleep( std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period> time )
{
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(time);
}
```

And this could be a member function of a class.  But what about the following case?

```
class UsesDuration
{
public:
   template <typename Rep, typename Period>
   UsesDuration( std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period> dur ) :
      my_duration(dur) { }

   void doSomethingPeriodic()
   {
       while( some_condition )
       {
          std::this_thread::sleep_for(my_duration);
          somethingInteresting();
       }
   }    

private:
   ???  my_duration;   /* How do I declare this??? */
}
```

Is there a clean way to keep the duration "abstract" A) ideally w/o turning the entire class into a templated class, B) by turning the class into a class template?

Comment: This is one of the problems introduced by the overly complex `std::chrono`; the first time I saw this thing I thought it was a joke. A template with two parameters (one of which relating to *compile time rational arithmetic*) just to represent a time duration is pure madness. Just use `double` to store seconds as any other sane language does and forget about all these artificial non-problems, `sleep_for` resolution is far worse than `double`'s anyway.

Comment: Why not use one of the helper types, like `std::chrono::milliseconds` depending on the desired granularity ?

Comment: @MatteoItalia - Interesting take on it...   I'm still (slowly) re-learning C++ (C++03 just came out when I was in college, mostly done C professionally), and having trouble deciding what new features are "better" vs "different" than older-style c++ / just calling into C.  But I think you might be right on std::chrono being a little overkill.

Comment: I do like the ability to cast between seconds, nanoseconds etc though. You can even forget that it's a horrible template underneath if you just stick to the predefined types.

Comment: @dgel: of course that's neat, but if the price of having that is to make *everything* that is slightly time-related a `template`, thanks but no thanks. Sometimes I feel that several parts of the library of this kind were perfected and included in the standard out sheer of excitement that someone actually managed to make some neat feature work out from the type system, ignoring the fact that way simpler solutions are actually simpler to use and to implement. It's a sad state of affair that C++ now has two time libraries - one too rudimentary, one too overengineered for real-world use.

Comment: @MatteoItalia:  Respectfully, you simply do not understand what you're talking about.  Please take the time to learn it before spreading misinformation about it.

Comment: @HowardHinnant: respectfully, I did read about chrono and it seems to me an over-engineeered solution looking for a problem, and a complete miss from what is actually needed. A four-arguments template class to represent a time duration, a header completely devoted to compile-time rational arithmetic, surely that's what I needed, not some object oriented (*or at least reentrant*) functionality to deal with time or dates to forget about the ugliness of `<cdate>`. Please take the time to learn from almost any other language how to implement a time library that is actually useful.

Comment: (and my real fear is that this is a *trend* that the standard library is following; C++11 brought us some great additions such as lambdas, `std::function` & co., but on the other hand is dangerously leaning on masturbatory navel-gazing stuff like this)

Comment: @MatteoItalia: I am assuming you would use `double` also for time points, and `double`'s resolution is too low for nanoseconds even at around only a value of 1 million seconds. I don't know what epoch you want to use, but that's less than a fortnight. Another problem with `double` is the inability to represent many simple decimal fractions, and the non-associative addition and multiplication, which are both sure to surprise people.

Comment: Sorry, it's ca. 4.5 million seconds, or slightly more than 52 days since the epoch at which double becomes unable to represent nanoseconds. Even before that there can be unexpected rounding, though.

Comment: @MatteoItalia C++ has different goals than other programming languages so obviously C++ is going to have a different solution to the same problem. The reason double is not used is straight forward: nobody wants to use floating point arithmetic to keep track of time on performance constrained systems. You should understand the goals before you dismiss the solution.

Comment: @JordanMelo: best is enemy of good. Recent C++ has a tendency of providing either the most general solution ever (which may be wrangled to something useful if beaten with enough force) or providing nothing; the Stockholm syndrome that affects the C++ community doesn't help (see the [ridiculous and ridiculously upvoted answer to this trivial question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30967131/214671)). Performance constrained systems need special considerations anyway

Comment: @JordanMelo: (if using FP is a problem probably you don't even have efficient 64 bit integers, so you have to rethink everything in 32 or even 16 bits, which in turn will have to make you think about all possible overflows you can have if you want to store anything in sub-millisecond precision or have long uptimes). My point is: it's essentially impossible to build something truly generic that is going to actually work transparently and efficiently from `rdtsc` on x86 to the RTC on an Arduino; instead of hoping to fulfill such a goal, it would be more sensible to provide something that works

Comment: @JordanMelo: fine at the center of the bell curve, people on the edge have to make their tools anyway. It's as in the "split an std::string" situation linked above: give me useful functionality that I can reasonably use in most cases (std::string => std::vector<std::string>), if I need something more sophisticated - hey, it's C++, I can go as low level as I like and build it as it suits best to the task at hand. That's the reason why people use frameworks like Qt: most of times, it's much better to use a handy average-case solution than to live with the tradeoffs of an overly general one.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One solution I can see for this is to just use a particular duration in you class and then you can use [`std::chrono::duration_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/duration_cast) to cast from the type supplied to the constructor to the type you use as the class member.  This allows you to not template the class but still take in any type of duration

```
template <typename Rep, typename Period>
   UsesDuration( std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period> dur ) :
      my_duration(std::chrono::duration_cast<decltype(my_duration)>(dur)) { }
```

Comment: This is probably what I'll do.  That or go with Matteo's suggestion and just store a double.

Comment: I'd sooner store a type that actually mentions what it represents rather than a double, which could be anything (ms? seconds?). The standard types also prevent you from passing seconds to a function which expects ms, and allows you to easily cast between them. If you forget that they're horrible templates underneath, they're actually quite nice

Comment: Better yet, do `template<typename Duration> UsesDuration(Duration d) : my_duration(duration_cast<decltype(my_duration)>(d)) {}`

Comment: @JoelCornett I added the `decltype` part.  Still getting used to using that.  I am hesitant to change the template types as that is what the OP had but it is a good suggestion.  I wonder which way would give a better error message if a non duration was passed.

Comment: @dgel It doesn't prevent you from passing seconds to something expecting milliseconds - it automatically converts it.

Comment: Upvoted.  This is a fine solution in addition to my answer.

Answer (score 42):

A simpler solution is to just use a `std::chrono::duration` that is as fine or finer than you'll ever want:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

class UsesDuration
{
public:
   UsesDuration( std::chrono::nanoseconds dur ) :
      my_duration(dur) { }

   void doSomethingPeriodic()
   {
       while( some_condition )
       {
          std::this_thread::sleep_for(my_duration);
          somethingInteresting();
       }
   }

   void somethingInteresting();

private:
   std::chrono::nanoseconds  my_duration;
};

int
main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    UsesDuration x{5min};
}
```

There is no need to template everything, unless you actually **want** that generality.  All of your predefined units implicitly convert to `nanoseconds`.  If you ever get into a state where the client is sending something that won't *exactly* convert to `nanoseconds`, you will find out at compile-time, and *then* you can decide if you want to template, or perhaps go with another solution.

Another solution, which is better than storing a `double`, is to store a double-based duration:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

class UsesDuration
{
public:
   UsesDuration( std::chrono::duration<double> dur ) :
      my_duration(dur) { }

   void doSomethingPeriodic()
   {
       while( some_condition )
       {
          std::this_thread::sleep_for(my_duration);
          somethingInteresting();
       }
   }

   void somethingInteresting();

private:
   std::chrono::duration<double>  my_duration;
};

int
main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    UsesDuration x{5min};
}
```

*Every* `chrono::duration` will implicitly convert to a floating-point duration.  In this example I've chosen seconds as the precision, and double as the representation.  You could choose anything you want (long double and microseconds, whatever).

You have a lot of options here.  And all of them give you type safety that a bare `double` won't, and without sacrificing performance nor flexibility.

> Just use double to store seconds

is the worst advice you can get.  *Learn* `<chrono>`.  It has a lot of flexibility, and there is a great deal of it that doesn't demand templates.

---

It was perhaps impolite of me to insist that you learn `<chrono>` without giving you some pointers.

[Nicolai M. Josuttis' "The C++ Standard Library - A Tutorial and Reference, 2nd Edition"](http://www.cppstdlib.com) has an excellent introduction to `<chrono>`.  This chapter alone will pay for the cost of the book.  Be sure you get the 2nd edition.  His first edition covered C++03, which did not have `<chrono>`.  Disclosure:  I have no arrangement (financial or otherwise) to promote Nico's book, though he is a friend of mine.

For those willing to dig into committee papers, the `<chrono>` proposal is here:

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2661.htm

The section on `duration` (linked in the contents) is where I suggest you start if you are impatient.  It reads more like a tutorial than a technical paper as I was attempting to bring the committee itself up to speed.  It includes the very advice I have given in my answer above, and more.

And here is a video introductory tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P32hvk8b13M

Comment: is there a way to make my_duration a static constant?
i tried lots of things and ended up with something my clang and mingw53 (I'm using qt 5.8) didn't complain about:
constexpr static std::chrono::milliseconds every_duration {10000ms};
but then the symbol every_duration is undefined in constructor O_o

Comment: @d.Candela:  Yes, put `constexpr std::chrono::milliseconds UsesDuration::every_duration;` *outside* the class definition, in a .cpp, in addition to what you already have.  Also you can initialize with `10s` to make your initialization more readable.